# Running opengl jogamp from jar

Tags: java, opengl, jar

I've written a program that uses opengl that I have been running without issue form within eclipse, and I now want to package it up into a jar for deployment.

I'm using maven to manage all the dependencies and the build process.  I've done a clean and package to build a jar with all the necessary dependencies, but I'm having trouble getting it to actually run.

It seem to be looking for files outside of the jar file, for example gluegen-rt.dll, which I can see is in the jar at the top level. It also seems like it's trying to reference a version of my jar with '-natives-windows-amd64' appended to the name.

When I try and run it I get the following error:

```
D:\My Documents\workspace\Cube\target>java -jar cube-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar 10 OPENGL
Catched FileNotFoundException: D:\My Documents\workspace\Cube\target\cube-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies-natives-windows-amd64.jar (The system cannot find the file specified), while addNativeJarLibsImpl(classFromJavaJar class com.jogamp.common.os.Platform, classJarURI jar:file:/D:/My%20Documents/workspace/Cube/target/cube-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/com/jogamp/common/os/Platform.class, nativeJarBaseName
cube-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies-natives-windows-amd64.jar): [ file:/D:/My%20Documents/workspace/Cube/target/cube-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -> file:/D:/My%20Documents/workspace/Cube/target/ ] + cube-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies-natives-windows-amd64.jar -> slim: jar:file:/D:/My%2520Documents/workspace/Cube/target/cube-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies-natives-windows-amd64.jar!/
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: D:\My Documents\workspace\Cube\target\gluegen-rt.dll
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibraryInternal(JNILibLoaderBase.java:551)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.access$000(JNILibLoaderBase.java:64)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase$DefaultAction.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.java:96)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.java:414)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.DynamicLibraryBundle$GlueJNILibLoader.loadLibrary(DynamicLibraryBundle.java:388)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform$1.run(Platform.java:209)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:179)
        at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.<clinit>(GLProfile.java:83)
        at ui.jogl.JOGLCube.init(JOGLCube.java:52)
        at ui.jogl.JOGLCube.<init>(JOGLCube.java:44)
        at ui.jogl.JOGLCubeController.<init>(JOGLCubeController.java:19)
        at core.Cube.getVirtualCube(Cube.java:37)
        at core.Cube.<init>(Cube.java:27)
        at core.Cube.main(Cube.java:56)
```

I have no prior experience working with OpenGL so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to get your application in a single jar.  JOGL is a pretty sophisticated library of several jars (and optionally DLLs, too) that must be installed correctly in the same folder as your application jar.

I don't know exactly how to set this up in Eclipse (my experience is Netbeans, which IMO is a much more robust build environment) but the issue is that the DLLs for the native part of JOGL are not being found.  JOGL uses a slightly crazy method: the DLLs are packaged in jar files, and the library dynamically expands them in place at run time, then attaches them. The name of this file for your architecture is `jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64.jar`.  In general, you should have all these jars with names of the form `jogl-all-natives-*.jar` in the same directory as your app's jar file.

The problem with the above is that the user of your app must have write permission in a place from which DLLs can be loaded.   This can conflict with many enterprise security policies (enforced e.g. by Active Directory push).  If you have a wide user population, this will not work for enough users to cause serious pain. The app I've been working on must run in schools internationally.  There is no way the all-in-one JAR mechanism can be used for this.

The other way forward is to use the separate native DLLs in the `lib` folder of the `jogamp` distribution, placing them in a lib directory that's on the `java.library.path` of the application.

In all cases, you will need an installer to place the multiple jars, DLLs, and perhaps other files of your system in the right places.  I use [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) for this.  It's not as polished as a commercial installer builder, but it's good enough to do multi-jar Java app installers.  If you want to check out the way my JOGL app handles installation for Windows and Mac, see [Bridge Designer and Contest](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wpbdc).

A final note is that if you don't have perfect control over the machines where your app will deploy strongly consider packaging a Java Runtime in your installer.  Dealing with the gajillipon ways users can dork up java installation is not much find.  A built-in JRE makes the download package much bigger, but in my experience, this causes much less pain than the alternative of dealing with what's on the user machine.

This information (albeit in a not so readable format) is documented on [the JOGL deployment Wiki](http://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/deployment/JOGL-DEPLOYMENT.html#NativeJARFiles).

Comment: Our method isn't crazy, SWT and LibGDX do something similar, it's optional, it can be disabled. When it is still enabled, if there is a problem with a directory, it might be caused by a bug fixed recently that prevented GlueGen from creating a temporary directory under Windows in some particular cases. Otherwise, feel free to make a request for enhancement to allow the developer to pass a custom directory to store the native libraries, it would be a lot easier than what you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I do it for my game (Truly Unusual Experience of Revolution®). It's currently supported. Please look at this page of the wiki:
http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/JogAmp_JAR_File_Handling

You have to follow a certain layout to allow GlueGen to find your native libraries for JOGL, JOAL and JOCL:
http://forum.jogamp.org/Packaging-JOGL-projects-to-be-cross-platform-tp4031261p4031286.html

If your project is under GPL, feel free to look at my Ant target "create-jars" in my Ant build script:
http://svn.code.sf.net/p/tuer/code/pre_beta/build.xml

You don't need to set the Java library path, you don't need to use the DLLs, just use the JARs containing the Java libraries and those containing the native libraries.

Keep in mind that the defaut archiver (Ark, WinRAR, ...) might open your JAR when double-clicking on it instead of running your application. I advise you to wrap your JAR into a native application bundle. You can use Packr, Launch4j or NSIS to do so. My script above uses my Ant target "create-app" (inspired by Packr, still using its native launcher) for Mac OS X to create a .app zipped file. Good luck.

P.S: If you're "bothered" by my use of the GPL, you can look at my tutorial for [JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation](http://tinyurl.com/mpuu8or) that deals with this aspect.